# Вставка из истории буфера

Tags: intellij-idea

Есть такая хорошая комбинация <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> в Intellij Idea, данная комбинация показывает историю буфера обмена и возможность оттуда брать ранее скопированные данные. Но беда в том что там хранится всего 5 последних копирований, возможно ли в настройках увеличить его размер хотя бы до 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно:

```
File > Setting > Editor > Generals>Limits: number of contents to keep in clipboard.
```

Там по умолчанию стои 5, меняешь на 20. Готово)

А вот тут есть все про `Copy Paste`
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html

Comment: Спасибо, работает